# Can I use TCPClient's underlying socket with Socket.Select?

Tags: c#, .net-core

My server uses Socket.Select heavily, so that it never blocks, and I want to use SSL. As far as I can tell there is no such thing as SSLSocket or smth like that. I have to use TCPListener, accept client and then wrap client's stream with SSLStream. My question is: after all the authentication business is done can I use TCPClient's underlying socket with Socket.Select? Poll underlying socket for events, but for actual communication use stream's Read and Write methods? If Socket.Select reports socket is ready to read/write, does it guarantee that stream's Read/Write methods wouldn't block?

Comment: The TCPListener and TCPClient inherits the basic Socket class but limits the number of properties.  To get all the socket properties the Listener has Server which has the rest of the socket properties and the Client has Client which has the rest of the socket properties.

Comment: I know that. It doesn't answer my question though